# How to fix Bluetooth "Connection" switch greyed out?

Tags: bluetooth, 15.10

I am not able to connect to any Bluetooth device.

The below "Connection" switch is greyed out for any kind of Bluetooth device. All of them work in connection with my Android device (i.e. the devices are not broken).

[image]

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:21f3]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 AGN [8086:1311]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04f2:b2ea Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera [ThinkPad]
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0a5c:21e6 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702 Bluetooth 4.0 [ThinkPad]
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I can search for new bluetooth devices. Therefore, I don't think that it's a firmware-related issue.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks for your comment! I edited my question.

Comment: You need to install firmware.

Comment: @Pilot6 I edited my question. Please take a look. I don't think it's the same problem as linked above.

Comment: You need firmware. Windows driver provides it. The solution is the same. Other devices may behave differently without the firmware.

Answer (score 2):

I could solve the problem by re-pairing the devices.